# React. How redux-persist rehydrate after login?

Tags: reactjs, redux-persist

if the user fills out the form for a long time, the token can expire. When the user logs in again, needing to download the data. If it's the wrong user, delete it.

now it work Example:
1 persist/PERSIST
2 persist/REHYDRATE auth
3 persist/REHYDRATE root
4 request isAuth account: true
5 request getAuth account: {userId: 1}
this load root in state before auth and save account: true

**How I can rehydrate root after authorization? or back to initial root after another user login?**

Store:

```
  const initialize = (initialState?: IRootState, middlewares = []) => {
  const store = createStore(reducerPersist, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...defaultMiddlewares, ...middlewares)));
  const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {});
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

rootReducer

```
const authTransform = createTransform(
  (inboundState: IAccount) => ({ userId: inboundState.userId }),
  (outboundState: IAccount) => (outboundState),
  { whitelist: ['account'] }
);

const authConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
  whitelist: ['account'],
  transforms: [authTransform]
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  authentication: persistReducer<AuthenticationState>(authConfig, authentication),
  locale,
... +50 another reducers
```

my persist-reducer

```
export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  RESET: 'persist/RESET'
};

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: [
    'formBlockState',
    'formCommentBlockState'
  ],
 stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};
const rootReducer = (state: IRootState, action) => {
  if (action.type === ACTION_TYPES.RESET) {
    persistConfig.whitelist.forEach(key => state[key] = undefined);
  }
  return reducer(state, action);
};
const reducerPersist = persistReducer<IRootState>(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default reducerPersist;

export const clearPersist = () => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.RESET
});
```

app

```
const { store, persistor } = initStore();

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

const render = Component =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <AppContainer>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              <Component />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </AppContainer>
    </ErrorBoundary>,
    rootEl
  );
```

render(AppComponent);

in AppComponent

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

      async loadData() {
        await this.props.isUserAuthenticated();
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
          await this.props.getSession();
          await this.props.getProfile(); 
          ...
```

this.props.isUserAuthenticated - return state.account - true // replace persist:auth
this.props.getSession - return state.account.userId // old userId - clear
initial state set in reducers in combineReducer
if I write

```
  if (action.type === ACTION_TYPES.RESET) {
    state = undefined);
  }
  return reducer(state, action);
```

I have error in components get field state

**How I can rehydrate root after authorization? or back to initial root after another user login?**